# Understanding $\zeta(s, x+y) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1} (-y)^{k} \zeta(s+k,x) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, riemann-zeta

Currently, I'm trying to understand how the the [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_zeta_series#Polygamma-related_series) $$\zeta(s, x+y) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1} (-y)^{k} \zeta(s+k,x) $$ is derived.

I know that that the following derivative, a shift, is [relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Taylor_series): $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial q} \zeta(s,q) = -s \zeta(s+1,q). $$
Following the approach in the link above, one finds \begin{align}\zeta(s,x+y) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{k}}{k!} \frac{\partial^{k}}{\partial x^{k}} \zeta(s,x) \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1} (-y)^{k} \zeta(s+k,x). \qquad \qquad(*) \end{align}

In part, I understand equation $(*)$, but not fully. I see that \begin{align} \frac{1}{k!}\frac{\partial^{k}}{\delta x^{k}} \zeta(s,x) &= (-1)^{k}s(s+1)\dots(s+k-1)\zeta(s+k,x) \\
&= \binom{s+k-1}{s-1} \zeta(s+k,x), \end{align}
but there is some part of the equation I don't understand:

- Where does the $x+y$ part come from in $\zeta(s,x+y) $ in $(*)$?

Furthermore, I don't see how the equation $$\zeta(\nu+2) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+\nu+1}{k} [ \zeta(k+\nu+2)-1  ] \qquad \qquad (**) $$ results from $(*)$. It is mentioned in the wiki article that $y=-1$ is chosen, but which value of $x$ is then picked?

Comment: What do you mean with 'where does the $x+y$ part come from' ? At first they are positive real numbers, then we can extend to complex numbers . At the end of your question $x=2$ (as $\zeta(s)-1=\zeta(s,2)$)

Comment: @reuns Thank your for answering the second question. As for the first one: I don't see why the $x+y$ part is present in the Taylor series, and why that yields the sum with only $y^{k}$, and x is only in $zeta(s,x)$ (not outside it).

Comment: You said so, it is the Taylor series at $y=0$ of the function $y\to \zeta(s,x+y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's remember the definition of the Hurwitz zeta function
\begin{eqnarray*}
\zeta (s,q)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+q)^s}.
\end{eqnarray*}
We will also need the following useful formula
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{k} X^k =\frac{1}{(1-X)^s}.
\end{eqnarray*}
It is actually a total doddle from here ... invert the order of the plums, do the $k$ plum & ... definition of HZ again.

> $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{k} (-y)^k \zeta(s+k,x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{k} (-y)^k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+x)^{s+k}} \\ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+x)^{s}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{k}  \frac{(-y)^k }{(n+x)^{k}} \\ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+x)^{s}}\frac{1}{\left( 1+ \frac{y }{n+x} \right)^s} = \zeta(s,x+y) $$

Comment: Thank you! That is a useful formula indeed.

Comment: Quick question: is there perhaps a minor error in the formula? Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{(1-X)^{s}} $ ? As that is what you seem to have applied in the spoiler.

Comment: Yes, this is a mistake & your suggestion corrects it ... Thank you Max $\ddot \smile$